# Wheatgrass in thalassaemia

Tags: physiology, hematology

In local newspapers there was a not so recent story about wheatgrass juice being "curative" in thalassaemia. Although I do not take the article at face value, it would be enlightening to know if there was any basis at all in the claims that wheatgrass juice or extract can help mitigate some symptoms of thalassaemia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wheatgrass juice or extract has shown some promise for reducing the required frequency of blood transfusions in thalassemic patients, possibly due to iron chelating activity.  However, few high-quality controlled studies have been conducted so it may be too early to form a definite conclusion.

References:

- Choudhary, Dharma R.; Naithani, Rahul; Panigrahi, Inusha; Kumar, Rajat; Mahapatra, Manoranjan; Pati, Hara Prasad; Saxena, Renu; Choudhry, Ved P. (April 2009). "Effect of wheat grass therapy on transfusion requirement in β-thalassemia major". *The Indian Journal of Pediatrics* **76** (4). pp. 375—376. doi:[10.1007/s12098-009-0004-6](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s12098-009-0004-6).
- Das, Priyabrata; Mukhopadhyay, Ashis; Mandal2, Suvra; Chandra Pal, Bikas; Mishra, Raghwendra; Mukherjee, Debarati; Mukhopadhyay, Soma; Basak, Jayasri; Kar, Manoj (2012). "In vitro studies of iron chelation activity of purified active ingredients extracted from *Triticum aestivum* Linn. (wheat grass)". *European Journal of Medicinal Plants* **2** (2). pp. 113—124. doi:[10.9734/EJMP/2012/1059](http://dx.doi.org/10.9734/EJMP/2012/1059).
- Marwaha, R.K.; Bansal, Deepak; Kaur, Siftinder; Trehan, Amita (July 2004). ["Wheat grass juice reduces transfusion requirement in patients with thalassemia major: A pilot study"](https://www.indianpediatrics.net/july2004/716.pdf). *Indian Pediatrics* **41**. pp. 716—720.
- Mukhopadhyay, S.; Basak, J.; Kar, M.; Mandal, S.; Mukhopadhyay, A. (2009). ["The role of iron chelation activity of wheat grass juice in patients with myelodysplastic syndrome"](http://hwmaint.meeting.ascopubs.org/cgi/content/abstract/27/15S/7012). *Journal of Clinical Oncology* (Meeting Abstracts) **27** (15S). p. 7012.
- Singh, Karnail; Pannu, M. S.; Singh, Palwinder; Singh, Jaswinder (January 2010). "Effect of wheat grass tablets on the frequency of blood transfusions in thalassemia major". *The Indian Journal of Pediatrics* **77** (1): 90—91. doi:[10.1007/s12098-010-0002-8](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s12098-010-0002-8).
- Tirgar, P. R.; Desai, T. R. (September 2011). ["Investigation into iron chelating activity of *Triticum aestivum* (wheat grass) in iron-dextran induce iron overload model of thalassemia"](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Dr_Pravin_Tirgar/publication/252971855_Investigation_into_iron_chelating_activity_of_Triticum_aestivum_(wheat_grass)_in_iron-dextran_induce_iron_overload_model_of_thalassemia/links/02e7e51f6165eb9415000000.pdf). *Journal of Pharmacy Research* **4** (9). ISSN [0974-6943](https://www.worldcat.org/issn/0974-6943).